# How to enable SLI in Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: nvidia

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 installed on a server that has two GTX 1080 Ti.

How to enable SLI?

Note: `nvidia-xconfig --sli=on` gives the following error: `No package 'xorg-server' found` because there is no GUI installed.

Comment: You need a desktop for that to work.